# add css classes in velocity template

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, velocity

How we can add css classes in velocity template.

I tried

`<span class="test"> text to show </span`

When I check this in email it's showing like

```
<span class > text to show </span
```

How I can place this class attribute in VM file?

Answer (score 0):

It's inserting exactly what you told it to. You need to make sure that your e-mail MIME type is set to `text/html` so that the client will interpret it as HTML.